# Am I following the MVVM pattern correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Did I break the rules of MVVM if ever have that rule?
Did I connect my database correctly?

My XML

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewBox="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7.ViewModel"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7.ViewModel.Command"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewBox:viewModel x:Key="testView"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource testView}}">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="175,47,0,0" Text="{Binding fname, Source={StaticResource testView}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,95,0,0" Command="{Binding test, Source={StaticResource testView}}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="175,81,0,0" Text="{Binding mname, Source={StaticResource testView}}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="175,109,0,0" Text="{Binding lname, Source={StaticResource testView}}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="175,175,0,0" Text="{Binding IDNum}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my ViewModel Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfApplication7.ViewModel.Command;
using WpfApplication7.Model;
namespace WpfApplication7.ViewModel
{
    public class viewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private databaseTest obj = new databaseTest();
        public btnTest test { get; set; }
        public viewModel()
        {
            test = new btnTest(this);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

            }
        }

        public string fname
        {
            get { return obj.firstname; }
            set { obj.firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("fname");
            }
        }
        public string mname
        {
            get { return obj.middlename; }
            set { obj.middlename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("mname");
            }
        }
        public string lname
        {
            get { return obj.lastname; }
            set { obj.lastname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("lname");
            }
        }

        public int IDNum
        {
            get { return obj.idNum; }
            set { obj.idNum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IDNum");
            }
        }

        public void searchBtn()
        {

            obj.sql = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source = C:\Users\veekat\Documents\VeeKat.mdb";
            obj.conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(obj.sql);
            obj.cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from info where ID = "+ this.IDNum +"", obj.conn);

            try
            {
                obj.conn.Open();
                obj.dr = obj.cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (obj.dr.Read())
                {
                    this.fname = obj.dr["Firstname"].ToString();
                    this.mname = obj.dr["Middlename"].ToString();
                    this.lname = obj.dr["Lastname"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Command class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication7.ViewModel.Command
{
    public class btnTest : ICommand
    {    
        public viewModel viewM { get; set; }

        public btnTest(viewModel vw)
        {
            this.viewM = vw;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            viewM.searchBtn();
        }
    }
}
```

And here my Model Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace WpfApplication7.Model
{
   public class databaseTest
    {
        private string Firstname;
        private string Middlename;
        private string Lastname;

        public string firstname
        {
            get { return Firstname; }
            set { Firstname = value; }
        }

        public string middlename
        {
            get { return Middlename; }
            set { Middlename = value; }
        }

        public string lastname
        {
            get { return Lastname; }
            set { Lastname = value; }
        }

        private int num;

        public int idNum
        {
            get { return num; }
            set { num = value; }
        }

        public string sql { get; set; }
        public OleDbConnection conn { get; set; }
        public OleDbCommand cmd { get; set; }
        public OleDbDataReader dr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So far I don't have any errors, but I want to know your opinion.
[as you can see, i search it using the id number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwsB6.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: im sorry for that ... this is my first post here im sorry ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVVM pattern you followed is not incorrect. But it could be improved.

In my opinion the best thing to do is to separate the database related stuff to a new class file.

Add a new class file **DBManager** and add all the database related CRUD operations inside the class file. Make this class a singleton class. It's upto you. The use of separating the db operations is that when your project becomes very large, it is easy to manipulate data when it is in a single file, rather than dealing it in every model.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question "is it good practise to place my database IO inside my MVVM ViewModel ?" In which case a good discussion of this can be found in this [MVVM where to put Data Access Layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717621/mvvm-where-to-put-data-access-layer) "MVVM where to put Data Access Layer?" which should point you in the right direction.