# WPF MVVM properties binding not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have created a view model which has a single property for a student model, that I am then binding to a control in my XAML. But nothing is appearing when I execute the application.

I am setting data context in my app.xaml.cs as follows:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)   
 {         
   base.OnStartup(e);

   Registrationformusinemvvm.MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

   VMUser VM = new VMUser();

   window.DataContext = VM;

   window.Show();

 }
```

Why is the binding not working?

This is my view model:

```
   public class VMUser:BaseClass
   {    
     private student _currentStudent;

     public student CurrentStudent
     {
         get { return _currentStudent; }
         set { 
               _currentStudent = value; 
               OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStudent");    
         }
     }
   }
```

My Student model class:

```
 public class student:BaseClass
 {      
   private string name="sumit";

     public string Name
     {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
     }

     private int rollNum;

     public int RollNum
     {
         get { return rollNum; }
         set { rollNum = value;OnPropertyChanged("RollNum"); }
     }

     private int phNum;

     public int PhNum
     {
         get { return phNum; }
         set { phNum = value;OnPropertyChanged("PhNum"); }
     }
     private string sub;

     public string Sub
     {
         get { return sub; }
         set { sub = value;OnPropertyChanged("Sub"); }
     }

 }
```

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Registrationformusinemvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Registrationformusinemvvm"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Registrationformusinemvvm.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <!--<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:VMUser/>
  </Window.DataContext>-->
  <Window.Resources>

 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14"       

    FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"   
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Roll Number" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14" 

   FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"   

   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Subject" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" 

  FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Phone Number" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  
  FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Name="tbName" Text="{Binding CurrentStudent.Name,Mode=TwoWay,   
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
Width="120" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Name="tbRollnum" Text="{Binding CurrentStudent.RollNum}" 
Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="120" Height="30"   
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Name="tbSub" Text="{Binding CurrentStudent.Sub}" 
Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="120" Height="30" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Name="tbPh" Text="{Binding CurrentStudent.PhNum}" 
Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="120" Height="30" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Name="tbSubmit" Content="Submit" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
Grid.Row="4" Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Can you check output window in Visual Studio when running and see if you get any binding exceptions? It might be that current student is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your binding isn't working because your _currentStudent is null by default. Initialize your _currentStudent if null.

```
    public student CurrentStudent
    {
        get { return _currentStudent = (_currentStudent ?? new student()); }
        set
        {
            _currentStudent = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStudent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: its working perfectly Thanks :)
am i correctly using MVVM pattern?
i am bit confused about where i will write my queries for database operation.in the moder or viewmodel?

Comment: From what I can see from the code above your doing fine, but to give a better answer I would have to see the structure of your project(s). Look you have a few options here. For example you can have an db context in your model, which you can then query directly from your VM, OR you can add another layer and use something like the repository pattern to handle your queries, which you can then call from your VM. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717621/mvvm-where-to-put-data-access-layer. Remember to mark this as the answer, so that it can hopefully help others as well.

Comment: thanks Bracher for your reply.
please share your email so that i can send my demo code.
i need some guidelines if you can give me ,i will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add OnPropertyChanged in your model class.

```
void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: in my base class i am writing this.

Comment: There is a race condition in that implementation. Either cache the value of `PropertyChanged` into a variable before invoking it or use the null-conditional operator: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop))`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your above code you cant assigned the value to CurrentStudent Property so
can you please check do you have the value to CurrentStudent property.

Thank you for your question

Answer (score -1):

Remove StartupUri="YourXamlFile.xaml" from **App.Xaml**